# How to change the cents form of SpellNumber macro function to "xx/100"

Tags: excel, vba, macros, edit

I have to spell numbers in excel but i need the cents form to be "xx/100"
Ex.
3,258.63 = "THREE THOUSAND TWO HUNDRED FIFTY EIGHT HUNDRED 63/100 ONLY"

Right now my macro function is

---

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
  'MAIN FUNCTION

'=SPELLNUMBER(95)
SUB TEST()
  MSGBOX SPELLNUMBER(95)
END SUB

FUNCTION SPELLNUMBER(MYNUMBER, OPTIONAL BMONEY = FALSE)
  DIM DOLLARS, CENTS, TEMP
  DIM DECIMALPLACE, COUNT
  DIM INUMBER

  REDIM PLACE(9) AS STRING
  PLACE(1) = " HUNDRED "
  PLACE(2) = " THOUSAND "
  PLACE(3) = " MILLION "
  PLACE(4) = " BILLION "
  PLACE(5) = " TRILLION "

INUMBER = MYNUMBER
' STRING REPRESENTATION OF AMOUNT.
MYNUMBER = TRIM(STR(MYNUMBER))

' POSITION OF DECIMAL PLACE 0 IF NONE.
DECIMALPLACE = INSTR(MYNUMBER, ".")
' CONVERT CENTS AND SET MYNUMBER TO DOLLAR AMOUNT.
IF DECIMALPLACE > 0 THEN
  CENTS = GETTENS(LEFT(MID(MYNUMBER, DECIMALPLACE + 1) & _
  "00", 2))
  MYNUMBER = TRIM(LEFT(MYNUMBER, DECIMALPLACE - 1))
END IF

COUNT = 1
DO WHILE MYNUMBER <> ""
    TEMP = GETHUNDREDS(RIGHT(MYNUMBER, 3))
    IF TEMP <> "" THEN DOLLARS = TEMP & PLACE(COUNT) & DOLLARS
    IF LEN(MYNUMBER) > 3 THEN
        MYNUMBER = LEFT(MYNUMBER, LEN(MYNUMBER) - 3)
    ELSE
        MYNUMBER = ""
    END IF
    COUNT = COUNT + 1
LOOP

IF BMONEY = TRUE THEN
  SELECT CASE DOLLARS
    CASE ""
      DOLLARS = "NO DOLLARS"
    CASE "ONE"
      DOLLARS = "ONE DOLLAR"
    CASE ELSE
     DOLLARS = DOLLARS & " DOLLARS"
END SELECT

SELECT CASE CENTS
  CASE ""
   CENTS = " AND NO CENTS"
  CASE "ONE"
    CENTS = " AND ONE CENT"
  CASE ELSE
    CENTS = " AND " & CENTS & " CENTS"
END SELECT
END IF
SPELLNUMBER = DOLLARS & CENTS
END FUNCTION


FUNCTION GETHUNDREDS(BYVAL MYNUMBER)
  DIM RESULT AS STRING
  IF VAL(MYNUMBER) = 0 THEN EXIT FUNCTION
  MYNUMBER = RIGHT("000" & MYNUMBER, 3)
  ' CONVERT THE HUNDREDS PLACE.
  IF MID(MYNUMBER, 1, 1) <> "0" THEN
      RESULT = GETDIGIT(MID(MYNUMBER, 1, 1)) & " HUNDRED "
  END IF
  ' CONVERT THE TENS AND ONES PLACE.
  IF MID(MYNUMBER, 2, 1) <> "0" THEN
      RESULT = RESULT & GETTENS(MID(MYNUMBER, 2))
  ELSE
      RESULT = RESULT & GETDIGIT(MID(MYNUMBER, 3))
  END IF
  GETHUNDREDS = RESULT
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION GETTENS(TENSTEXT)
  DIM RESULT AS STRING
  RESULT = "" ' NULL OUT THE TEMPORARY FUNCTION VALUE.
  IF VAL(LEFT(TENSTEXT, 1)) = 1 THEN   ' IF VALUE BETWEEN 10-19...
      SELECT CASE VAL(TENSTEXT)
          CASE 10: RESULT = "TEN"
          CASE 11: RESULT = "ELEVEN"
          CASE 12: RESULT = "TWELVE"
          CASE 13: RESULT = "THIRTEEN"
          CASE 14: RESULT = "FOURTEEN"
          CASE 15: RESULT = "FIFTEEN"
          CASE 16: RESULT = "SIXTEEN"
          CASE 17: RESULT = "SEVENTEEN"
          CASE 18: RESULT = "EIGHTEEN"
          CASE 19: RESULT = "NINETEEN"
          CASE ELSE
      END SELECT
  ELSE ' IF VALUE BETWEEN 20-99...
      SELECT CASE VAL(LEFT(TENSTEXT, 1))
          CASE 2: RESULT = "TWENTY "
          CASE 3: RESULT = "THIRTY "
          CASE 4: RESULT = "FORTY "
          CASE 5: RESULT = "FIFTY "
          CASE 6: RESULT = "SIXTY "
          CASE 7: RESULT = "SEVENTY "
          CASE 8: RESULT = "EIGHTY "
          CASE 9: RESULT = "NINETY "
          CASE ELSE
      END SELECT
      RESULT = RESULT & GETDIGIT _
          (RIGHT(TENSTEXT, 1))  ' RETRIEVE ONES PLACE.
  END IF
  GETTENS = RESULT
END FUNCTION

FUNCTION GETDIGIT(DIGIT)
  SELECT CASE VAL(DIGIT)
      CASE 1: GETDIGIT = "ONE"
      CASE 2: GETDIGIT = "TWO"
      CASE 3: GETDIGIT = "THREE"
      CASE 4: GETDIGIT = "FOUR"
      CASE 5: GETDIGIT = "FIVE"
      CASE 6: GETDIGIT = "SIX"
      CASE 7: GETDIGIT = "SEVEN"
      CASE 8: GETDIGIT = "EIGHT"
      CASE 9: GETDIGIT = "NINE"
      CASE ELSE: GETDIGIT = ""
  END SELECT
END FUNCTION
```

---

But that gives me the spelling on the cents as well, how can i leave the cents in numbers in the format of 50/100?

Many thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help getting the fraction part.

```
Right(FormatCurrency(MYNUMBER, 2), 2) & "/100"
```

Comment: this will be input in the decimals function? I have no background on vba macros. I do appologize in advance, and thanks

Answer (score 0):

---

```
' POSITION OF DECIMAL PLACE 0 IF NONE.
 DECIMALPLACE = INSTR(MYNUMBER, ".")
 ' CONVERT CENTS AND SET MYNUMBER TO DOLLAR AMOUNT.
 IF DECIMALPLACE > 0 THEN
     CENTS = RIGHT(FORMATCURRENCY(MYNUMBER, 2), 2) & "/100"
   MYNUMBER = TRIM(LEFT(MYNUMBER, DECIMALPLACE - 1))
END IF
```

---

Thanks to @Barney the decimals function was able to show as
50/100 (for example)